# Is anyone aware of any Public webserver that sends charset=SHIFT-JIS.?

Tags: web, http

I am looking for a public web server that servers text/html with charset=shift-jis.
I can find utf-16, most webservers are utf-8, I am finding it hard (even with google) to look for a web server that sends charset=shift-jis

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any such service, but you can easily create one.

For instance, it could read POST request body encoded in UTF-8, convert it to Shift-JIS and set it back.

You would need then a function that converts the text and a library to expose it as a REST service.

Comment: Was able to create my own. Thanks. Used editpad to create html in x-jis and served using nginx server.